# Custom role to allow download files and disable upload files in GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to create a custom role that only allow a group email to list and download the files. However, they're NOT ALLOWED to upload any files in specific bucket.

Which role should I use to create the custom role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the predefined role [Storage Object Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) for your use case,  which has the following permissions:

```
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
storage.objects.get
Storage.objects.list
```

Since we already have a predefined role, you will not be required to create a custom role.
If this doesn’t meet your requirements then please explain the question in detail.

If you have created a google group with the email addresses, then you might wanna look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration#group) link.